# Cloudera settings Sqoop import gives Java Heap Space error and GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, garbage-collection, cloudera

I have installed CDH latest version and set up a cluster with 1 master node of 16 GB RAM and 200 GB memory and 3 DataNodes of 8 GB RAM and 500 GB memory. When I try to run Sqoop import, it gives Java heap space error and GC overhead limit exceeded error after 83% of mapping is done. I have tried all the solutions present on the internet.

Here is a list of things I tried:

1. I tried increasing size of container as well the map and reduce memory limit as per the calculation given here

   http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html
2. I tried keeping Java heap size to 0.8 times of map and reduce memory limit

I want to know what could be the possible reason behind this and solution for it.

Comment: what's the size of heap of deamons that you run?

Comment: which deamons? if you are asking about java heap size property in cloudera manager it has been set to 820Mb approx(0.8 times of map memory(which is 1 Gib))

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and resolved by placing the proper MySQL/J Connector 5.1.33.

There were some issues with mysql 5.1.17 and Sqoop 4.1.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use Argument ?dontTrackOpenResources=true&defaultFetchSize=1000&useCursorFetch=true in connection string. it works without changing JVM.

Answer (score 0):

try 
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=6000 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx1600m -Dmapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=4800

I have given 1 mapper per million records.

Above parameters needs to be tuned according to the data for a successful SQOOP pull.